# argparse argument input as raw text or file

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Is there easy to get input using argparse whether it is raw text or file name based on prefix char, e.g.

```
python program.py -data @filename.txt
python program.py -data 'raw text'
```

so the above programs should be equivalent if content of `filename.txt` is `raw text`.

Comment: Nothing built-in. You'd have to implement this logic yourself, looking at the first character of the argument determine if it's the name of a file to read from or text to use directly.

Comment: There is support for something similar: [`python programs @filename.txt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars) would read *arguments* from a file, rather than reading the contents of a file to act as a single argument,.